# alternative to "Find All References" for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I use it for developing a ASP.NET web form Web site.
my problem is that "Find All References" which opens by right clicking on a type or member, do not search all over my solution.(only search in opened files and it's own project).
It wasn't like this in Visual Studio 2013.
It has been reported as bug in Visual Studio Connect and other feedback websites.
I want a tool to not only search in it's project and opened files, but in all solution's projects and in the web site's files.
It is a simple need, and a big IDE like Visual Studio should have that.

Is there any free tool?

Comment: may be for the time being u cud just search for your stuffs in total commander in the directory where your project folder is?

Comment: Search is not an alternative since for a common word like "order" , it may find a lot of occurrences which cannot be sure to be referencing our type.